# ASP.NET file size validator not validating

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

So I have a few ASP.NET file upload controls in my aspx file -

```
 <asp:FileUpload ID="fulNature" class="form-control summer" runat="server" /><asp:Labe ID="lblNature" runat="server" Text="Label" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
 <asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="fulNature" Display="Dynamic"
                        ErrorMessage="File size should not be greater than 1 MB." ForeColor="#FF3300" OnServerValidate="ValidateFileSize"></asp:CustomValidator>

<asp:FileUpload ID="fulIndustrial" class="form-control summer" runat="server" /><asp:Label ID="lblIndustrial" runat="server" Text="Label" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
<asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="fulIndustrial" Display="Dynamic"
                        ErrorMessage="File size should not be greater than 1 MB." ForeColor="#FF3300" OnServerValidate="ValidateFileSize"></asp:CustomValidator>
```

I'm trying to limit file size with one C# validator -

```
protected void ValidateFileSize(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
    var validator = (source as CustomValidator);
    string controlToValidate = validator.ControlToValidate;
    FileUpload SubmittedUpload = validator.NamingContainer.FindControl(controlToValidate) as FileUpload;

    if (SubmittedUpload.FileBytes.Length > 1048576) //  A little padding added.
    {
        args.IsValid = false;
    }
    else
    {
        args.IsValid = true;
    }
}
```

The issue is that the validator never fires regardless of file size.  I have to be missing something simple here, but I'm just not seeing it.

Comment: it will have to upload the whole file to work.

Comment: I should have mentioned - the file uploader validator is being used by multiple controls.  I edited my question to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

you can directly get the size of uploaded file:

```
long size=fulNature.FileContent.Length;
```

Comment: How is this different from the answer submitted 6 minutes ago?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
long filesize = SubmittedUpload.FileContent.Length;
```